# Rails 5 Api and Angular 4 active record associations (belongs_to and has_many)

Tags: angular, devise, ruby-on-rails-5.1

am trying to develop a SPA with rails 5 Api and Angular4 as frontend,i have devise and angular2-token working fine,my models are users and novels,I have a problem getting all novels that belong to a particular user even though i have the user_id reference in the novels model,Am new here please.

Novel Model

```
class Novel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules.
  has_many :novels
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
          :omniauthable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

My Novel Component on Angular

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  userEmail:string;
  novels: Array<NovelService>;
  constructor(public authService:Angular2TokenService,
    public http: HttpClient) {
      http.get('http://localhost:3000/novels').
      subscribe((res : NovelService[])=>{
        this.novels = res;
      });
  }
```

Comment: `user = User.find id` && `user.novels`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of those who might have similar issue, Active Model Serializer is all you need to get going [Here is the github link](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)

Answer (score 0):

`user = User.find id`  or

`user = User.find_by email: 'email'`

Then:

`user.novels` or

`Novel.where(user_id: user.id)`

Comment: Am talking about implementing something like this @user.novel which provides all novels that belong to the user.

Comment: @ChrisGeek You can instantiate the `@user = User.find id` then do `@user.novels`

Comment: the user has_many novels so it cant be `@user.novel` it is `@user.novels` run it on the rails console...

Comment: Alright bro,i will do just that, i actually forgot angular was only going to render what it gets from rails, so my whole db query should be done in rails while i render them using httpclient on angular?

Comment: @ChrisGeek yes you have to run the query from rails then pass it in json to your angular front end to parse and render the results

Comment: thanks a lot bro,my reputation is > 15 so i can't upvote your answer,but it really helped me.

Comment: You on whatsapp? would like to stay in touch. @iamcaleberic

Comment: I fixed it using activemodelserializer gem, for anyone with same problem,activemodelserializer is all you need.